# Erro na função UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

Estou com este erro ao tentar executar este update:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='1''
>   at line 2' in C:\wamp\www\siteOriginal\classes\funcionario.php on line
>   65

No caso a linha `65` é o execute, o que devo estar fazendo de errado ?

```
public function update($id){

    $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET cargo = :cargo, horastb = :horastb, salario = :salario, 
    WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cargo', $this->cargo);
    $stmt->bindParam(':horastb', $this->horastb);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sa`insira o código aqui`lario', $this->salario);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    return $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(':sa`insira o código aqui`lario', $this->salario); Vc não tá passando o nome da coluna, tá passando uma descrição cheia de acentos....Fora que não tenho certeza se o $this->table dentro da variável vai funcionar. Estranho.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está na query. Tem um vírgula a mais antes do **WHERE**, so remover que funciona.

```
$sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET cargo = :cargo, horastb = :horastb, salario = :salario,
WHERE id=:id";
```

Para:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET cargo = :cargo, horastb = :horastb, salario = :salario 
WHERE id=:id";
```